# QT C++ OPENGL and problem when run in other machines

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I would like to know how to make an application made with opengl be seen on other machines that do not have QT installed, I copied the plugins

- Platforms

  - qwindows.dll

And the dlls

- libEGL.dll
- libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
- libGLESV2.dll
- libstdc++-6.dll
- opengl32sw.dll
- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- Qt5OpenGL.dll
- Qt5Widgets.dll

In the program root but it still does not work. The application runs, but when creating the part of the “animation” the program is broken and sometimes I only get the widget in total black, help me please.

Comment: There's a tool called `windeployqt.exe` that comes with Qt that helps you package your application for distribution.

Comment: Yes, I use that tool but the problem is not that, the problem is that when I want to run the animation on another machine, the animation doesn't work. I was reading and apparently is for incompatibility in opengl between the machines. Is there any ANGLE or OPENGL installation that can be installed without having to install QT???